# How can I make menu shortcuts work when the program is in background?

Tags: delphi

I have an invisible menu with the shortcut F2. I want it to execute the code every time I press F2 even if the program isn't in focus. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to find this yourself, the first Google hit for *Delphi global hotkeys* get me [`this`](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/16). I don't want to post this as the answer because there are dozens of them on the net. Try to search before you ask the next time, please.

Comment: Oh. I tried googling 'accept shortcuts when window is not in focus' and the first pages didn't find anything. Didn't know it was called Global Hotkeys >.>

Comment: Ok, I see. Now you know it ;-) Just one note about [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Some of the examples ignores the result of this function, but this result might be important for you. If it returns True it tells you that your keystroke has been registered for you. But note you are not the only one application in the whole wide Windows so if you get False, it most probably means that someone else's application do this before you. So don't be surprised that if you get False and press F2, something else happens.

Comment: F2 is a poor choice for this. Most applications use F2 for something. If you steal that  then your users will hate your app and uninstall it. If this is for personal use, then it will just be you that is affected!

Comment: Which would you suggest then?

Comment: If it's for personal use, do whatever you like. If it is something that you hope other people will install then let them have control over the key so that they can make sure that it does not clash with a shortcut used in another program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to define a system-wide hot key.